# How to use SELECT with date_format, not working in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to adjust a SELECT in php so I can specify format of DATE columns and DATETIME columns, but I don't really know how since it works in mysql but not in php.

When using this, it doesn't work at all, I get nothing out of it at all:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(loan.delivered, '%d. %b %Y') AS 'delivered',
loan.username, loan.schoolbookid, loan.pickup, loan.deadline, student.email,
student.fname, student.lname, book.title
FROM schoolibrary.loan INNER JOIN student ON loan.username=student.username
INNER JOIN schoolbook ON loan.schoolbookid=schoolbook.id INNER JOIN book ON 
book.isbn=schoolbook.isbn;
```

With no DATE_FORMAT, like this, everything work (so it is not because of the other part of the php I would think):

```
SELECT loan.delivered,
loan.username, loan.schoolbookid, loan.pickup, loan.deadline, student.email,
student.fname, student.lname, book.title
FROM schoolibrary.loan INNER JOIN student ON loan.username=student.username
INNER JOIN schoolbook ON loan.schoolbookid=schoolbook.id INNER JOIN book ON 
book.isbn=schoolbook.isbn;
```

This is how I use that column if that matters:

```
<?php echo ($row['delivered']?:'not delivered'); ?>
```

The entire select works in mysql as I want it to with the format (with X. month XXXX), but when trying to format the date in the website all the information/other selections is removed/no results is shown even when everything worked earlier (everything works if I remove DATE_FORMAT and just use it as is)

And: Do i need to do anything different when formating DATE or DATETIME columns?

Comment: Why don't you do the formatting in php instead of mysql?

Comment: Please show the full PHP code for the query. Do you get the rest of the data, or no data at all? You should be able to echo the formatted column if the query works as expected

Comment: The format function call looks correct.
Make sure your column data type really is DATE or DATETIME
and note that the returned column type is a string.

Comment: I get nothing at all with the DATE_FORMAT in it and everything else is exactly the same 
 if I just use the second one I do get everything. It is a DATETIME does that make it any different? What are different in the PHP? I have normally just tried the SELECT... line in mysql to see if it works before I put it in PHP, but now it didn't work.